# Can I have an iframe that my doc can access, but not vice versa?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, xss, same-origin-policy

I know that iframes in web pages need to be very strict with same-origin policy, for sake of security.

My understanding is that, by not being in the same origin, the containing document and the contained iframe are *mutually* protected.

I am interested to know if there is a way to make the protection one-way only?

An example would be an iframe in which an untrusted input could be pasted without the risk to affect the containig document, but whose content is still accessible from the containing document.